# Control View in Bokeh State Map

Tags: geospatial, bokeh

I am trying to plot a state with county-level detail using Bokeh and want to be able to control the portion of the state that is visible.  I've seen some users suggest deleting counties, but I want to have a rectangular area based on lat/long parameters that controls what portion is shown.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the what is visible on the plot by specifying the x and y ranges. These can be specified either directly in the figure command or by setting the respective attributes using a Range1D. Bokeh will then allow interactive panning respecting while keeping the dimensions of the initial visible area.

If you want to then prevent the user from modifying the visible portion of the plot, you can simply create the figure without any zoom or resize tools.

---

Here's an example illustrating the above.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d

output_file("title.html")

# Specify tools for the plot
tools = "pan, reset, save"

# create a new plot with a range set with a tuple
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           x_range=(0, 20), tools=tools)

# set a range using a Range1d
p.y_range = Range1d(0, 15)

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=10)

show(p)
```

Comment: Happy to help @rsgny, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted